# Implementing svg export feature of jointjs in angular application

Tags: angular, svg, jointjs

Trying to add svg export feature of jointjs+ in angular application.
Ive added some images to the paper but the images are not exported properly in the downloaded svg file.
This is my code to implement svg download.

exportAsSVG() {
const exportOptions = {
padding: 20,
useComputedStyles: false,
size: "2x"
};
format.toSVG(
this.paper,
(svg) => {
util.downloadDataUri(
`data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svg)}`,
"jointjs+.svg"
);
},
exportOptions
);
}

Here is what i get after the svg export.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `convertImagesToDataUris` in your options object? Setting to `true` should convert all contained images.
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.7/format.SVG.html#format.SVG.configuration

```js
paper.toSVG(function(svgString) {
    console.log(svgString);
}, {
    convertImagesToDataUris: true
});
```